# Errors trying to install Acumos Boreas release

Tags: acumos

Having a hope that the Acumos Boreas OneClick (and other install scripts) actually work now...

I am trying, on behalf of the [AI4EU project](https://www.ai4eu.eu/)  (Task 3.2) to install the Acumos Boreas release on an Ubuntu 18.04 server again. Unfortunately my hope is dwindling...

I am following the procedure under section 2.1.2 here:
https://docs.acumos.org/en/boreas/submodules/system-integration/docs/oneclick-deploy/user-guide.html#host-vm-preparation

I am starting from a fresh Ubuntu 18.04 Virtual Machine (created with 32G Memory, 12 Cores and 300 GB disk).

Doing this (and typing the sudo password when prompted):

```
git clone https://gerrit.acumos.org/r/system-integration
cd system-integration/tools/
bash setup_docker.sh
if [[ "$(id -nG "$USER" | grep docker)" == "" ]]; then sudo usermod -aG docker $USER; fi
# Logged out and in again and verified that my user is in the docker group
cd system-integration/tools/
bash setup_k8s_stack.sh setup
cd
bash system-integration/AIO/setup_prereqs.sh k8s acumos.tele.no $USER generic 2>&1 | tee aio_prep.log
# When "Prerequisites setup is complete" messages is displayed I continue with
cd system-integration/AIO
bash oneclick_deploy.sh 2>&1 | tee aio_deploy.log
```

The deployment fails with the following error message:

```
....
oneclick_deploy.sh setup_federation:233 (Tue Aug 20 13:47:04 UTC 2019) CDS API is not yet ready; waiting 10 seconds
+ t=300
+ sleep 10
++ curl -k -u ccds_client:27f928e9-cdde-4483-b3c9-7da074972908 https://acumos.tele.no/ccds/peer
++ grep -c numberOfElements
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   203  100   203    0     0   7000      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  7000
+ [[ 0 -eq 0 ]]
+ [[ 300 -eq 300 ]]
+ fail 'CDS API is not ready after 300 seconds'
+ set +x
```

When I use the Kubernetes Dashboard to see what actually fails I do see that the common-dataservice pod fails.

I can also see that the docker_proxy apparently crashes regularly as well as some other pods.

All install and error logs are available here:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/61snwd26zbixwl3/AAAWcfBKnIwNkRghXSMQayrEa?dl=0

If anyone is able to guide me on how to make an install of Acumos Boreas for the AI4EU project (WP3) to explore on it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: thanks for posting logs, the CDS failure is a name resolution problem, it fails to resolve the database server called "acumos" to an IP addy.  I'll ping our expert.

Comment: Why is it trying to find acumos (when I have stated that acumos.tele.no is the FQDN)?

Nevertheless, nslookup on the acumos server for name acumos (locally) gives this:
Server:  127.0.0.53
Address: 127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name: acumos
Address: 193.156.17.73

Comment: I think the JDBC URL given to the Common Data Service uses bare "acumos" as the name of the database server.  This name might only be resolvable from within a container running in K8S. You didn't say whether you ran nslookup on the machine that is the K8S host, or within a running container.

Comment: The nslookup command above was done on the machine (but I expect the same to be true from within a Docker container unless the container makes some strange network configuration).

Comment: Yes, K8S and Docker have very sophisticated networking and DNS features.  The answer outside and the answer inside are likely to be very different.

Answer (score 0):

Arne, make sure that you can connect to the host 'acumos' from within the running CDS container. If this is a cloud service VM, you may have to open a security group rule to allow the VM to connect to itself on its public IP (sounds implicit, but isn't always the default). You can test this out via

kubectl exec -it -n acumos $(kubectl get pods -n acumos -l app=sv-scanning | awk '/sv-scanning/{print $1}') -- curl http://acumos:30001

NOTE: This command example uses the sv-scanning container because it has curl installed... the test is however to see if *any* container can connect to MariaDB. By default, if the Acumos domain is not DNS-resolvable, as indicated by an entry in the /etc/hosts file, a hostAlias will be added to each deployment template.

(update) I added a script to create a debug container (ubuntu based) and run it as a pod under the namespace. That way you can add any tools you want to debug, e.g. I have already installed curl, j1, netcat. Use that container to verify connectivity to http://acumos:30001, check out the CDS logs, etc.

```
#!/bin/bash
kubectl delete deployment -n acumos debug
while [[ "$(kubectl get pods -n acumos -l app=debug)" != "" ]] ; do
  echo 'waiting...'; sleep 10
done
cat <<EOF >debug.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: acumos
  name: debug
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: debug
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: debug
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: debug
        image: ubuntu
        command: ['/bin/bash', '-c']
        args:
        - apt-get update; apt-get install -y curl jq netcat;
          sleep 3600;
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /logs
          name: logs
      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:
      - name: logs
        persistentVolumeClaim:
         claimName: logs
EOF
kubectl create -f debug.yaml
# Wait till running
while [[ $(kubectl get pods -n acumos -o yaml -l app=debug | grep -c 'phase: Running') -eq 0 ]]; do
  echo 'waiting...'; sleep 10
done
kubectl exec -it -n acumos $(kubectl get pods -n acumos -l app=debug -o name | sed 's/pod\///') -- bash
```

Comment: Not possible to do that since the sv-scanning pod has status CrashLoopBackOff. This is also the case for the docker-proxy and dsce pods.

Comment: The FQDN domain acumos.tele.no is by the way globally DNS resolvable and locally on the VM the shortname acumos is also resolvable to the same IP address. The VM is under our control in our own datacenter. It is however behind a strict firewall (for incoming traffic). It is nevertheless open for outgoing traffic on all ports.

Comment: I.e. we do have an entry in the /etc/hosts file on the VM mapping the name acumos to the correct IP address. The FQDN acumos.tele.no has been added properly to DNS.