# CDS API is not ready after 300 seconds

Tags: acumos

Background： VMware15.0 ubuntu16.04-64bit 32G RAM + 16Core CPU /etc/hosts: 192.168.79.130 localhost

Doing this (and typing the sudo password when prompted):

```
git clone https://gerrit.acumos.org/r/system-integration
apt-get -y update
apt-get -y install docker-ce=18.06.3~ce~3-0~ubuntu
if [[ "$(id -nG "$USER" | grep docker)" == "" ]]; then sudo usermod -aG docker $USER; fi
sudo visudo #add
jp ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
# Logged out and in again and verified that my user is in the docker group
cd system-integration/tools/
sudo bash setup_k8s_stack.sh setup
cd
sudo bash system-integration/AIO/setup_prereqs.sh k8s localhost $USER generic 2>&1 | tee aio_prep.log
# When "Prerequisites setup is complete" messages is displayed I continue with
cd system-integration/AIO
sudo bash oneclick_deploy.sh 2>&1 | tee aio_deploy.log
```

The deployment fails with the following error message:

```
oneclick_deploy.sh setup_federation:233 (Mon Sep 23 18:50:43 PDT 2019) CDS API is not yet ready; waiting 10 seconds
+ t=300
+ sleep 10
++ curl -k -u ccds_client:187bbf19-40b9-45c8-9945-4903292d963d https://localhost/ccds/peer
++ grep -c numberOfElements
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   203  100   203    0     0    872      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   878
+ [[ 0 -eq 0 ]]
+ [[ 300 -eq 300 ]]
+ fail 'CDS API is not ready after 300 seconds'
+ set +x
```

I would be grateful if someone could guide me to solve this problem.

PS：

```
jp@ubuntu:~$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                                                    READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
acumos        acumos-nginx-ingress-controller-54f4989d47-7nl2k        1/1     Running            0          4m20s
acumos        acumos-nginx-ingress-default-backend-66575548bf-jzfpz   1/1     Running            0          4m20s
acumos        azure-client-55f9bb779-rrw8x                            1/1     Running            0          2m14s
acumos        cds-5ff84ccc8f-wzh5d                                    0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   4          4m14s
acumos        docker-dind-699c6c9846-8tc8t                            1/2     CrashLoopBackOff   5          4m34s
acumos        docker-proxy-6b4f6f7c85-jvhdf                           1/1     Running            0          112s
acumos        dsce-59c686d6d7-lgrx5                                   1/1     Running            0          2m46s
acumos        federation-7578f48f8b-6n5cg                             1/1     Running            0          3m54s
acumos        filebeat-7f7c7dc87f-fshkg                               1/1     Running            0          4m48s
acumos        kubernetes-client-7fdfdb96bb-jhrfn                      1/1     Running            0          2m32s
acumos        msg-7d9d96c775-sttx7                                    1/1     Running            0          2m57s
acumos        onboarding-868669c6c6-9tpp8                             1/1     Running            0          3m12s
acumos        portal-be-c6fd97f4c-7575f                               1/1     Running            0          3m24s
acumos        portal-fe-6bc6d6c9d6-gkprl                              1/1     Running            0          3m34s
acumos        sv-scanning-66f997ccf5-rz676                            1/1     Running            0          2m6s
```

Comment: I don't see a database pod in the running list above. Also the list of pods shows the CDS container cds-5ff84ccc8f-wzh5d crashed. Please fetch the logs from that container, maybe post here.  I suspect that CDS fails to reach a database. If no DB is running that would explain it :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@chrisinmtown Thank you for your guidance. It's really because there's no DB that causes this problem. Because the environment configuration("**..\AIO\acumos_env.sh**") is incorrect, the environment configuration is changed to:

```
export ACUMOS_DEPLOY_MARIADB=false
export ACUMOS_SETUP_DB=false
export ACUMOS_DEPLOY_NEXUS=false
export ACUMOS_DEPLOY_ELK=false
```

The initial default configuration is:

```
export ACUMOS_DEPLOY_MARIADB=true
export ACUMOS_SETUP_DB=true
export ACUMOS_DEPLOY_NEXUS=true
export ACUMOS_DEPLOY_ELK=true
```

Comment: The AIO allows you to reuse an existing database OR install a new one and initialize it.  Maybe the default configuration is for an existing database?